# Objective-C IF statement with OR condition

Tags: objective-c, ios

What's wrong in this IF statement?

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"aaa" || currentElement isEqualToString:@"bbb"])
```

XCode says:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'isEqualToString:isEqualToString:'
```

I'm into an NSXML Parser procedure if it can help, but I think it's not that the problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You must compare result of two method calls:

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"aaa"] || [currentElement isEqualToString:@"bbb"])
```

The code you have actually compiles as

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:(@"aaa"||currentElement) isEqualToString:@"bbb"])
```

that is compiler tries to call non-existing `isEqualToString:isEqualToString:` method of NSString

Comment: Yeah... I'm an idiot. I can say in my defense that I'm still a newbie to Objective-C but... that's why this website is for, naah? :D

Comment: @AlbertoSchiariti yep, no worries :)