# Using OR || operator within if statement to assess variable (to be not equal to two(2) strings)

Tags: ios, sorting, if-statement, nssortdescriptor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using `NSUserDefault` (user defaults) to determine whether "Lists Sort Ascending" - the lists obtained from my Core Data stack using an `NSFetchedResultsController` - are sorted ascending or not.

For example:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorPrimary = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:self.sortAttributePrimary ascending:listsSortAscending selector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Regardless of the user setting, there are two Entities for which this value will always be true i.e. `BOOL listsSortAscending = YES;`, to be specific, alphabetically sorted lists, such as a contact list.

The code following this sentence is an attempt to explain what I am attempting to achieve...

```
BOOL listsSortAscending = YES;
if ((![self.entity isEqualToString:@"Contact"]) || (![self.entity isEqualToString:@"TypeChild"])){
    listsSortAscending = [self.userDefaults boolForKey:kListsSortAscending];
}
```

Apart from the lists for those two entities that will always be sorted `ascending:YES`, the other entities will be sorted based on the user default `listsSortAscending`.

This code does not work however and I cannot seem to work out the syntax correct.

I have read a lot of Stack Overflow and other pages including [Objective-C IF statement with OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189809/objective-c-if-statement-with-or-condition), however I cannot seem to resolve this annoying syntax!!!

The code included below does work, however my obsessive compulsive traits are running strong today and I want to learn the correct syntax using the OR operator `||`.

```
BOOL listsSortAscending = YES;
if (![self.entity isEqual:@"Contact"]) {
    if (![self.entity isEqual:@"TypeChild"]) {
        listsSortAscending = [self.userDefaults boolForKey:kListsSortAscending];
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your first code checks for "entity != Contact OR entity != TypeChild" and the second one checks for "entity != Contact AND entity != TypeChild" ...

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, missed it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
if ((![self.entity isEqualToString:@"Contact"] && ![self.entity isEqualToString:@"TypeChild"])) {
```

It isn't really a syntax thing, its a negation thing. Sometimes it's easier to specify the positive case instead of the negative case. But your second section of code with the nested `if`s is actually an `&&` rather than an `||`.

Comment: Thanks @Wain, missed it completely. The code sample you suggested works perfectly. Understand now, not a syntax thing. The negation completely confused me.