# Objective-C: If statements using OR

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

The following statement compiles fine:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    if ([textField ==_telField]) {

}
```

However, the following statement throws the error: Expected Identifier

```
if ([textField ==_telField] || [1==1]) {
}
```

It throws an identical error if `[1==1]` is replaced by `[textField==_mobField]`

Can anyone explain what is going on here and whether it is possible to chain multiple OR conditionals in a row here?

Comment: Your first statement that "compiles fine" does not in fact compile fine.

Comment: And what's the point of the `1 == 1`? That will always be true which means your whole `if` statement will always be true which means there is no point to the `if` statement.

Comment: 1==1 is just a placeholder for something that will always be true.  That is point.  However, it throws an error  of 'Expected identifier'.  The question is what in the syntax is causing it to throw error 'Expected identifier' and how to chain different tests.

Comment: Matt, did you try it?  See this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189809/objective-c-if-statement-with-or-condition. It compiles fine for me.  The problem occurs when I add second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build off of @matt's answer:

You are mistaking square brackets with parenthesis:

```
if ([textField ==_telField] || [1==1]) { 
}
```

Should be

```
if ((textField ==_telField) || (1==1)) { // Parenthesis instead
}
```

or

```
if (textField ==_telField || 1==1) { // Nothing is fine too
}
```

**You can think of square brackets in Objective-C similar to using the double parenthesis for calling a function in other languages, like this:**

```
//Objective-C
[self myFunction]

//Swift
self.myFunction()
```

Additionally, as @rmaddy pointed out, `1==1` will always return true so you don't even need the if statement if you do that.

Comment: Ok, switching square brackets to parentheses fixed issue.  BTW, I got the idea for square parentheses from this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189809/objective-c-if-statement-with-or-condition.  The difference is probably that that was using isEqualToString instead of ==

Comment: @user6631314 "The difference is probably" Not "probably". Is. If you don't understand that `[...]` is for method calls, or that `isEqualToString:` is a method call while `==` is just part of an expression, you need to stop and learn the basics of C and Objective-C before you try to do any more coding. Even better, maybe learn Swift instead of Objective-C, since Objective-C seems to be a bit daunting.

Comment: @user6631314, I agree with matt completely. Try out Swift instead of Objective-C, it's much more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just throw square brackets into an Objective-C expression wherever you feel like it. Square brackets have very specific meaning(s) in Objective-C, and those meanings do not encompass any of what you are doing. Just delete them:

```
if (textField == _telField || 1 == 1) {
```

Comment: Ok, your answer if (textField == _telField || 1 == 1) {  does not throw error and similarly, if (textField==_mobField||1==1) does not throw error, however, what I really want is if (textField==_telField || textField==_mobField) and this still throws expected identifier error

Comment: I understand. But then it was foolish to construct your question around code you didn't "really want".

Comment: What was foolish was to say the code didn't compile without testing it yourself.  If you'd read question attentively you also would have read 'It throws an identical error if [1==1] is replaced by [textField==_mobField]'.  I put in 1==1 to test the case where the statement is certain to be true.  I appreciate your providing an answer, however, though I accepted WMios which solved my problem.